# Bootstrap Validator

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-validator

**Pessoal,**

Nao estou conseguindo colocar a validação do Bootstrap por completo... o Basico ja funciona, mas o restante nao...

Falta a parte de ficar verde com icone no lado direito de SUCESS ou ERROR

```js
<script>
  $('#se-form').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'No es valido',
      icon: {
      required: 'fa fa-asterisk',
      valid: 'fa fa-check',
      invalid: 'fa fa-times',
      validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
    }
    fields: {
      first_name: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
          message: 'El nombre no puede estar vacío'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
 <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta name="author" content="" />
 <link href="../favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"> 


 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php?page=equipInsert" method="post" id="se-form" data-toggle="validator">
<div class="container-fluid">

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-user se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Primer Nombre" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="first_name">Primer Nombre</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-user se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" data-minlength="3" data-error="Minimo de 3 caracteres." placeholder="Apelido" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="last_name">Apelido</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="email" id="email" type="email" data-minlength="4" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" data-error="Informe um e-mail correto." placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-key se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" data-minlength="6" data-error="Minimo de 6 caracteres." placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-key se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="password_reply" id="password_reply" type="password" data-minlength="6" data-match="#password" data-match-error="Atenção! As senhas não estão iguais."  placeholder="Contraseña Repetir" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="first_name">Contraseña Repetir</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-venus-mars se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione su opción</option>
        <option value="1">Masculino</option>
        <option value="2">Femenino</option>
      </select>
      <label for="gender">Gender</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="birth_date" id="birth_date" type="date" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="birth_date">Fecha de aniversário</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-phone se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="telephone" id="telephone" type="tel" min="13" data-minlength="13" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{4,6}-[0-9]{3,4}$" data-error="13 caracteres." placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-control" required>
      <label for="telephone">Teléfono</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 se-center">
    <i class="fa fa-users se-icon-m" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="nivel" id="nivel" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione su opción</option>
        <option value="1">Admin</option>
        <option value="2">Usuario</option>
      </select>
      <label for="nivel">Nivel</label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
<p align="center">
  <button type="reset" title="Resetar..." class="btn btn-warning" /> Resetar 
  <i class="fa fa-eraser se-icon-p"></i></button> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <button type="submit" name="insertEquip" title="Agregar..." class="btn btn-primary" />Agregar
  <i class="fa fa-save se-icon-p"></i></button>
</p>
</form>
<br>
<p align="center">
  <a href="index.php?page=equipList">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left se-icon-m"></i> Regressar
  </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seria bom colocar o link cdn do bootstrap-validator para rodarmos seu código e ver exatamente onde está o erro

Comment: Pronto, arrumei para rodar o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o que você pediu fiz diversas modificações, tanto no HTML quanto no script. Segue abaixo o código atualizado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#se-form').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'No es valido',
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      first_name: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'El nombre no puede estar vacío'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }); // bootstrapValidator
}); // document.ready
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap font-awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- bootstrap Validator css -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- bootstrap Validator JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

<form action="index.php?page=equipInsert" method="post" id="se-form" data-toggle="validator">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name">Primer Nombre</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Primer Nombre" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name">Apelido</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" data-minlength="3" data-error="Minimo de 3 caracteres." placeholder="Apelido" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="email" data-minlength="4" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" data-error="Informe um e-mail correto." placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" data-minlength="6" data-error="Minimo de 6 caracteres." placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password_reply">Contraseña Repetir</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="password_reply" id="password_reply" type="password" data-minlength="6" data-match="#password" data-match-error="Atenção! As senhas não estão iguais." placeholder="Contraseña Repetir" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-venus-mars se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione su opción</option>
        <option value="1">Masculino</option>
        <option value="2">Femenino</option>
      </select>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="birth_date">Fecha de aniversário</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="birth_date" id="birth_date" type="date" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telephone">Teléfono</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <input name="telephone" id="telephone" type="tel" min="13" data-minlength="13" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{4,6}-[0-9]{3,4}$" data-error="13 caracteres." placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nivel">Nivel</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users se-icon-m"></i></span>
      <select name="nivel" id="nivel" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione su opción</option>
        <option value="1">Admin</option>
        <option value="2">Usuario</option>
      </select>
      <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p align="center">
    <button type="reset" title="Resetar" class="btn btn-warning" /> Resetar
    <i class="fa fa-eraser se-icon-p"></i></button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" name="insertEquip" title="Agregar..." class="btn btn-primary" />Agregar
    <i class="fa fa-save se-icon-p"></i></button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou bem, mas o label que estava utilizando para subur a escrita, agora nao....

Comment: Não entendi o problema. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Me responderam aqui!!!
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271000/label-no-bootstrap
Obrigado pela sua ajuda